# Image Picker iOS Accessibility Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image, voiceover

I am trying to build an app that is also accessible. It has to do with images, and so I am using this free open source tool called ELCImagePickerController (https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController) as an image picker. It lets the user pick multiple images at a time. But this is not accessible. Voice Over is not selecting each individual image, but rather a whole row at a time.

I have tried adding a Voice Over label to each of the individual images in "ELCAsset.m" by adding:

```
    NSDate *date = [self.asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
    NSString *orientation = [self.asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyOrientation];
    NSString *type = [self.asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType];
    CLLocation *location = [self.asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];

    self.asset.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@. %@. %@. %@.", type, orientation, date, location];
```

and it is in this method:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
```

But instead of VoiceOver selecting one image, it selects a whole row at a time. This is what it does:

[image]

I want it to only select one  image at a time instead of a row. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Anything that VoiceOver focuses has the property `accessibilityElement` set to YES.  VoiceOver will not focus accessibility elements that are contained within other accessibility elements.  So, you have to do the following

```
NSDate *date = [self.asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
NSString *orientation = [self.asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyOrientation];
NSString *type = [self.asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType];
CLLocation *location = [self.asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];

self.asset.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@. %@. %@. %@.", type, orientation, date, location];

//And additionally:
self.superview.isAccessibilityElement = NO;
```

The superview, meaning the container view that is behaving as a row of images.  This may actually be self.superview.superview, or self.superview.superview.superview... Depending on how the container is implemented.

Comment: You may additionally have to implement the accessibility container protocol on that element.  In which case, you'd have to make a change to the framework, or drop the framework.